# Get specfic range for each value of a collection in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a MongoDB collection like this:

```
[
    {name:"John", lastName: "Doe", rate: 333, age: 23 },
    {name:"John", lastName: "Snow", rate: 444, age: 26 },
    {name:"Elliot", lastName: "Anderson", rate: 555, age: 28 },
    ....
]
```

My expected result is a list of minimum and maximum for numerical values and a list of unique ones for string values as blow:

```
{
     name: ["John", "Elliot"],
     lastName: ["Doe", "Snow", "Anderson"],
     rate: [333, 555],
     age: [23, 28]
}
```

The performance is really important to me as I have a large amount of data so I wanted to know what is the best solution to achieve this ?

And do I need to use another DB ?

Comment: "The performance is really important to me" - ah, you're entering territory of tradeoffs here. You can make this query instant by precalculating/updating the values on write time. But this means slowing down each write. Which of them is more important to you? :)

Comment: Yes of course it has trade-offs, But in this case I just care about read time the write time could be as much as it needs.

Comment: Well, there's your answer then: precalculation.

Comment: But what about different queries ? It makes a lot of possibilities, Let's say i want rate greater than some number or name equal to something, You can't just precalculate everything.

Comment: It would be helpful if you state *all* of your requirements upfront when asking for advice.

Comment: You can use [MongoDB aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) to achieve this, it's your best shot for ad-hoc queries like this. You can also make the query faster by creating indexes for the fields that would require sorting e.g the rate field. And no, I don't think you need a new database.

Comment: @OTZ Yes I looked it before but I wasn't able to make it out for this problem. Can you give an example ?

Answer (score 1):

[MongoDB aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) is your best shot for ad-hoc queries like this. This is an example of how you can use MongoDB aggregation to achieve the result you described in the question:

```
const pipeline = [
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null, // This is set to null so that we can touch all the documents in the collecion
      name: { $addToSet: '$name' }, // Add all the name uniquely into an array
      lastName: { $addToSet: '$lastName' }, // Add all the lastName uniquely into an array
      maxAge: { $max: '$age' }, // Get the max age
      minAge: { $min: '$age' }, // Get the min age
      maxRate: { $max: '$rate' }, // Get the max rate
      minRate: { $min: '$rate' } // Get the min rate
    }
  },
  {
    $project: { // Reshape the output document
      _id: false,
      name: '$name',
      lastName: '$lastName',
      age: ['$minAge', '$maxAge'],
      rate: ['$minRate', '$maxRate']
    }
  }
]

// Let's say the data is stored in collections "users"
db.users.aggregate(pipeline);

/* This would output something like this:
{ 
  "name" : [ "John", "Elliot" ], 
  "lastName" : [ "Doe", "Snow", "Anderson" ], 
  "age" : [ 23, 28 ], 
  "rate" : [ 333, 555 ]
}
*/
```

As for the performance, it really does depends on the size of your collection as this query would most likely have to scan through every document in the collection, however, it's still your best shot given the possible dynamics of the query as you explained in the comment to the question.